# How to catch DataGridView auto sorting event

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can i catch datagridview auto sorting event. I want when changing data in datagridview while sorting do something else.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datagridview1.Sort(datagridview1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
```

Comment: Can not you change the data before sorting?

Comment: yes , but i want while auto sorting for example show message box.

Comment: You need to read documentation on datagridview events on MSDN. SortCompare Event might be useful to you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You should take over the process of sorting by implementing a [CollectionViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource) on the grid which will allow you to provide the necessary feed back you feel is adequate as the view/filter is being created and data being displayed.